# High Poly bake to low poly

Tags: uv, normals, baking

I'm just playing around with Cycles, trying to bake a normal map onto a low poly mesh.  After a bit of trying, this is the best I could do, however, it's clearly not correct.

[image: Poor UV normal map bake]

I'm not 100% sure how to improve it.  I've been reading about cages, but after messing about with larger/smaller cages, it didn't seem to make much difference.

Maybe I've UV unwrapped it incorrectly, or perhaps there is something I'm overlooking?  I'm still reading up on how to do this properly, however I'm a little confused.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Update:
Blend file is available here: [image]

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see how are your meshes and from which positions you are running the bake. Could you upload your file? Please use this link to do it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Where is the low poly in your file? Cube.004?

Comment: It is not there: only high poly and a curve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55676/discussion-between-tony-and-lemon).

Comment: For me the biggest problem seems to be the mapping. That's where your visible dots at the corner comes from. The form is cylindric, so i would try to map it cylindric. And not flat from above as you tried here. That way the edges of the 3d meesh aligns much better with the pixels fo the 2d texture.

Comment: You're not going to be able to catch detail at a 90 degree to your low poly surface.  Rays will always travel parallel to these surfaces.  You're left with a tiny bit of detail that gets smeared out by sampling and resolution limits.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help. However when baking is giving me issues I reset the unwrap with: U then select reset while in edit mode. delete doubles with: w remove doubles in edit mode. Press control N to recalculate normal's in edit mode.Then finally re unwrap using smart project. then bake, it usually fixes any issues I have.